# Combined dataframes with sum function in frequency tables

Tags: pandas

I have the following output from log analysis and want to use pandas to combine these outputs from multiple servers to determine the total frequency of each entry across all servers. I have renamed the items for privacy, but each entry is unique per server and common across servers.

Wondering how pandas can add the frequencies together when the entry name matches.

Thanks.

```
6201            entry1
63              entry2
4               entry3
3               entry4
3               entry5
2               entry6
1               entry7
1               entry8
1               entry9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.groupby` and apply `.agg`, passing `sum` to sum up all values in each group:

```
df.groupby('entries').agg('sum')
```

Modified your data a bit:

```
In [610]: df
Out[610]: 
   values entries
0    6201  entry1
1      63  entry2
2       4  entry3
3       3  entry1
4       3  entry4
5       2  entry3
6       1  entry3
7       1  entry2
8       1  entry2

In [611]: df.groupby('entries').agg('sum')
Out[611]: 
         values
entries        
entry1     6204
entry2       65
entry3        7
entry4        3
```

---

Alternatively, using `.sum()` directly:

```
In [612]: df.groupby('entries').sum()
Out[612]: 
         values
entries        
entry1     6204
entry2       65
entry3        7
entry4        3
```

Comment: @mobone You can also call `.sum()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do that:

```
In [121]: df
Out[121]:
   values entries
0    6201  entry1
1      63  entry2
2       4  entry3
3       3  entry1
4       3  entry4
5       2  entry3
6       1  entry3
7       1  entry2
8       1  entry2

In [122]: df.set_index('entries').sum(level=0)
Out[122]:
         values
entries
entry1     6204
entry2       65
entry3        7
entry4        3
```